# pasar variables en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy empezando a crear un CRUD. En el método index del controlador he puesto esto:

```
public function index(){
    $productos=Producto::get();
    return view('productos.index')->with('productos',$productos);
}
```

Y en la vista index.blade.php:

```
foreach($productos as $producto)
    echo "<tr>";?>
    <td class="text-center">{{$producto->id}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{$producto->nombre}}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{$producto->precio}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('producto.show',$producto->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Ver</a> 
    </td><?php
    echo "</tr>";
```

Al intentar ejecutar la aplicación en el navegador me dice que no encuentra $productos:

> "Undefined variable: productos (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ad\dam2d\resources\views\productos\index.blade.php)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a :

```
public function index(){
  $productos=Producto::get();
  return view('productos.index' , compact("productos"));
}
```

doy por hecho que la ruta de 'productos.index' en el Routes esta bien configurado.

Comment: El problema era que tenía que poner \App\ en el controlador: $productos=\App\Producto::get();

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla puedes auto responder tu propia pregunta añadiendo la solución y aceptarla. Ya que aceptar una respuesta que no soluciona el problema puede dar lugar a confusión para otra personas con problemas similares.

Comment: No entiendo el motivo del voto positivo en esta respuesta, ni por qué fue aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

Respondo esta pregunta con el fin de explicar el verdadero problema y dar una solución con mejores prácticas que den una guía a los futuros visitantes de como usar y aprovechar Laravel.

---

Teniendo en cuenta que el OP indica que su problema era no incluir el namespace de `Producto`, según el estándar [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#3-namespace-and-use-declarations) (el cual es utilizado por Laravel), la declaración para incluir la clase por medio de `use` es preferible, por consiguiente el código del controlador quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Producto;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $productos = Producto::get();

        return view('productos.index')->with('productos', $productos);          
    }

    // otros métodos
}
```

En cuanto a la vista, hay que recordar que en Blade no es necesario usar los tags `<?php ... ?>` por ningún motivo, al igual que con `echo`, esto es una mala práctica. La sintaxis correcta es:

```
@foreach($productos as $producto)
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">{{$producto->id}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{$producto->nombre}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">{{$producto->precio}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{ route('producto.show', $producto->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Ver</a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```